# A function that is continuous almost everywhere is Lebesgue measurable

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

If $f: E \to \mathfrak{M}$ (where $\mathfrak{M}$ is the Lebesgue measurable sets) is continuous a.e., is it true that $f$ is Lebesgue measurable?

I know that continuous functions on $E \in \mathfrak{M}$ are Lebesgue measurable, but I am wondering if this can be extended to functions that are continuous a.e.?

My intuition is that the answer is yes.

Let $D = \{x \in E: f(x) \text{ discontinuous}\}$ and $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$. Then:

$f^{-1}((-\infty, \alpha)) = ((\{x \in E: f(x) < \alpha\} \setminus D) \cup (\{x \in E: f(x) < \alpha\} \cap D))$

The second set is a subset of $D$, which has measure 0, so it is measurable. But is the first set also measurable? Is there any easier way to prove (or disprove) the statement?

Comment: The first set is of the form $\mathcal{O} \setminus (D \cap \mathcal{O})$ where $\mathcal{O}$ is open, and $D \cap \mathcal{O}$ is a subset of a set of measure zero.

Comment: @T.Bongers $\{x \in E : f(x) < \alpha\}$ is not open necessarily

Comment: @T.Bongers there’s no reason why the first one should necessarily be open. If $f$ is the 0 function on $[0,1]$ then it is continuous and for any positive $\alpha$, $\{x \in [0,1] : f(x) < \alpha\} = [0,1]$.

Answer (score 2):

The first set is open, hence measurable.

Edit: indeed, the first set is not open. 
However, let us denote $S_1$ the first set, $S_2$ the second one, $S=S_1 \cup S_2$. Then $S_2$ has null measure and $S_1 \subset S’ \subset S=S_1 \cup S_2$ where $S’$ is the interior of $S$. 
So $S$ has symmetric difference of null measure with its interior, thus is measurable.

Edit2: Let $x \in S_1$. Then $f(x) < \alpha$ and $f$ is continuous at $x$. Thus, there exists an open interval $J$ containing $x$ such that if $y \in J$, $f(y) < \alpha$, hence $x \in J \subset S$, and since $J$ is open, $x \in S’$.

Comment: wrong that it's open

Comment: Is it? Maybe I’m missing something but that doesn’t seem obvious to me.

Comment: You are right, I am editing.

Comment: +1 nice :)......